# Pandas Dataframe: Fill Missing Months

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I've seen this done with the Panda Timeseries, but was hoping to get some help with Dataframes. I have a file of monthly values from 1966-2009. I do not have data for the year 1985 and would like to add data for 2010/2011 as well. These additions would simply have NaNs attached to them.

With the code below, I'm trying to cut my dataset so that it starts at 1980 and then add in the years that are missing with NaN values attached. However, nothing gets cut and nothing is added. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
idx = pd.date_range('01-01-1980','12-31-2011',freq='M')
years = np.arange(1980,2012,1)

obdata = pd.read_table('H:/Dissertation/Data/Observations/'+str(int(statid[e]))+'.txt',index_col='datetime',parse_dates={'datetime':[3,4]},date_parser=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m'),keep_date_col='True')
o_d = obdata.loc[obdata['Year'].isin(years)]
o_d['sd'] = np.nan_to_num(o_d['sd'])
o_d.reindex(idx,fill_value='NaN')

grouped_same.append(o_d['sd'])
```

Some sample data is now provided. As you can see, 1985 is missing and the data stops at 2009. I will turn all the NaNs into 0s and I want to fill the missing monthly data with 'sd' as NaN.

```
ID      Lat     Lon     Year Month  sd
32539   53.12   157.75  1978     1  127.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1978     2  150.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1978     3  152.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1978     4  139.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1978     5  63.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1978     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1978     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1978     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1978     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1978    10  2.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1978    11  17.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1978    12  79.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1979     1  72.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1979     2  113.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1979     3  129.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1979     4  109.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1979     5  51.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1979     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1979     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1979     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1979     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1979    10  22.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1979    11  68.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1979    12  90.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1980     1  183.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1980     2  217.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1980     3  218.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1980     4  201.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1980     5  133.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1980     6  32.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1980     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1980     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1980     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1980    10  20.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1980    11  56.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1980    12  78.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1981     1  108.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1981     2  125.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1981     3  124.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1981     4  108.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1981     5  42.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1981     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1981     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1981     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1981     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1981    10  16.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1981    11  38.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1981    12  66.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1982     1  94.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1982     2  131.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1982     3  127.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1982     4  101.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1982     5  29.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1982     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1982     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1982     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1982     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1982    10  12.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1982    11  28.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1982    12  66.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1983     1  108.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1983     2  121.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1983     3  133.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1983     4  128.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1983     5  66.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1983     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1983     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1983     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1983     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1983    10  11.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1983    11  35.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1983    12  72.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1984     1  87.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1984     2  163.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1984     3  185.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1984     4  154.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1984     5  79.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1984     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1984     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1984     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1984     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1984    10  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1984    11  44.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1984    12  76.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1986     1  148.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1986     2  160.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1986     3  178.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1986     4  131.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1986     5  61.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1986     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1986     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1986     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1986     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1986    10  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1986    11  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1986    12  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1987     1  73.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1987     2  102.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1987     3  142.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1987     4  128.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1987     5  75.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1987     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1987     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1987     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1987     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1987    10  19.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1987    11  56.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1987    12  84.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1988     1  98.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1988     2  120.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1988     3  144.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1988     4  134.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1988     5  70.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1988     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1988     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1988     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1988     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1988    10  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1988    11  58.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1988    12  109.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1989     1  113.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1989     2  156.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1989     3  181.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1989     4  168.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1989     5  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1989     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1989     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1989     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1989     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1989    10  8.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1989    11  46.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1989    12  92.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1990     1  102.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1990     2  131.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1990     3  153.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1990     4  132.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1990     5  53.25
32539   53.12   157.75  1990     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1990     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1990     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1990     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1990    10  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1990    11  28.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1990    12  56.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1991     1  83.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1991     2  118.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1991     3  118.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1991     4  127.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1991     5  69.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1991     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1991     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1991     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1991     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1991    10  18.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1991    11  27.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1991    12  56.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1992     1  62.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1992     2  107.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1992     3  133.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1992     4  122.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1992     5  74.25
32539   53.12   157.75  1992     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1992     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1992     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1992     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1992    10  3.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1992    11  33.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1992    12  64.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1993     1  80.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1993     2  96.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1993     3  101.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1993     4  120.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1993     5  78.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1993     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1993     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1993     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1993     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1993    10  10.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1993    11  36.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1993    12  81.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1994     1  125.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1994     2  209.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1994     3  199.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1994     4  205.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1994     5  132.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1994     6  49.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1994     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1994     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1994     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1994    10  3.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1994    11  34.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1994    12  61.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1995     1  76.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1995     2  96.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1995     3  125.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1995     4  142.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1995     5  43.75
32539   53.12   157.75  1995     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1995     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1995     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1995     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1995    10  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1995    11  34.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1995    12  55.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1996     1  142.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1996     2  162.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1996     3  152.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1996     4  191.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1996     5  85.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1996     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1996     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1996     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1996     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1996    10  4.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1996    11  41.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1996    12  99.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1997     1  185.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1997     2  232.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1997     3  239.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1997     4  218.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1997     5  141.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1997     6  43.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1997     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1997     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1997     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1997    10  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1997    11  29.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1997    12  80.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1998     1  121.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1998     2  130.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1998     3  127.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1998     4  123.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1998     5  85.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1998     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1998     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1998     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1998     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1998    10  26.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1998    11  45.67
32539   53.12   157.75  1998    12  78.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1999     1  132.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1999     2  142.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1999     3  168.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1999     4  150.50
32539   53.12   157.75  1999     5  77.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1999     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1999     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1999     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1999     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  1999    10  7.00
32539   53.12   157.75  1999    11  43.33
32539   53.12   157.75  1999    12  83.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2000     1  90.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2000     2  94.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2000     3  98.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2000     4  91.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2000     5  48.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2000     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2000     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2000     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2000     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2000    10  34.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2000    11  56.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2000    12  67.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2002     1  130.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2002     2  121.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2002     3  136.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2002     4  151.50
32539   53.12   157.75  2002     5  51.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2002     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2002     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2002     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2002     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2002    10  12.50
32539   53.12   157.75  2002    11  23.33
32539   53.12   157.75  2002    12  48.33
32539   53.12   157.75  2003     1  71.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2003     2  91.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2003     3  105.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2003     4  100.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2003     5  61.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2003     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2003     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2003     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2003     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2003    10  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2003    11  34.33
32539   53.12   157.75  2003    12  76.33
32539   53.12   157.75  2004     1  109.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2004     2  128.33
32539   53.12   157.75  2004     3  138.33
32539   53.12   157.75  2004     4  127.50
32539   53.12   157.75  2004     5  66.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2004     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2004     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2004     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2004     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2004    10  6.50
32539   53.12   157.75  2004    11  52.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2004    12  105.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2005     1  156.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2005     2  205.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2005     3  273.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2005     4  216.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2005     5  117.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2005     6  41.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2005     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2005     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2005     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2005    10  10.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2005    11  38.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2005    12  108.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2006     1  191.50
32539   53.12   157.75  2006     2  199.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2006     3  195.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2006     4  209.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2006     5  109.50
32539   53.12   157.75  2006     6  44.50
32539   53.12   157.75  2006     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2006     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2006     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2006    10  9.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2006    11  8.33
32539   53.12   157.75  2006    12  27.33
32539   53.12   157.75  2007     1  54.33
32539   53.12   157.75  2007     2  67.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2007     3  145.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2007     4  124.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2007     5  55.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2007     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2007     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2007     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2007     9  16.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2007    10  1.50
32539   53.12   157.75  2007    11  36.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2007    12  74.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2008     1  119.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2008     2  125.50
32539   53.12   157.75  2008     3  153.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2008     4  124.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2008     5  43.25
32539   53.12   157.75  2008     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2008     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2008     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2008     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2008    10  16.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2008    11  56.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2008    12  103.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2009     1  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2009     2  181.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2009     3  190.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2009     4  175.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2009     5  81.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2009     6  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2009     7  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2009     8  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2009     9  NaN
32539   53.12   157.75  2009    10  14.00
32539   53.12   157.75  2009    11  43.67
32539   53.12   157.75  2009    12  79.00
```

Comment: Note that pandas reindex does not operate in place, it returns a new DataFrame, which you're not keeping.

Comment: Hi, how did you get all these data? Is it possible to do the fixed you said when you created the data? For example, if the data was generated from a program, then is it possible to change that program so that you can have all the fixes?

Answer (score 1):

I think better is use `periodindex` by converting `datetimeindex` by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html).

You can [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) in column `sd` to `0` and use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with filling `np.nan`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

obdata = pd.read_csv('H:/Dissertation/Data/Observations/'+str(int(statid[e]))+'.txt', index_col='datetime', parse_dates={'datetime':[3,4]},date_parser=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m'),keep_date_col='True')
#print obdata.head(100)

#convert string column Year to int (maybe you can omit it)
obdata['Year'] = obdata['Year'].astype(int)

#change datetimeindex to periodindex
idx = pd.date_range('01-01-1980','12-01-2011',freq='M').to_period('m')
years = np.arange(1980,2012,1)

#change datetimeindex to periodindex
obdata.index = obdata.index.to_period('m')

#fill NaN to 0 in column sd
obdata['sd'] = obdata['sd'].fillna(0)

o_d = obdata.loc[obdata['Year'].isin(years)]

#reindex and add NaN
o_d = o_d.reindex(idx,fill_value=np.nan)
```

```
            ID    Lat     Lon  Year Month      sd
1980-01  32539  53.12  157.75  1980     1  183.00
1980-02  32539  53.12  157.75  1980     2  217.00
1980-03  32539  53.12  157.75  1980     3  218.00
1980-04  32539  53.12  157.75  1980     4  201.50
1980-05  32539  53.12  157.75  1980     5  133.67
1980-06  32539  53.12  157.75  1980     6   32.00
1980-07  32539  53.12  157.75  1980     7    0.00
1980-08  32539  53.12  157.75  1980     8    0.00
1980-09  32539  53.12  157.75  1980     9    0.00
1980-10  32539  53.12  157.75  1980    10   20.50
1980-11  32539  53.12  157.75  1980    11   56.67
1980-12  32539  53.12  157.75  1980    12   78.33
1981-01  32539  53.12  157.75  1981     1  108.33
1981-02  32539  53.12  157.75  1981     2  125.33
1981-03  32539  53.12  157.75  1981     3  124.00
1981-04  32539  53.12  157.75  1981     4  108.67
1981-05  32539  53.12  157.75  1981     5   42.00
1981-06  32539  53.12  157.75  1981     6    0.00
1981-07  32539  53.12  157.75  1981     7    0.00
1981-08  32539  53.12  157.75  1981     8    0.00
1981-09  32539  53.12  157.75  1981     9    0.00
1981-10  32539  53.12  157.75  1981    10   16.00
1981-11  32539  53.12  157.75  1981    11   38.67
1981-12  32539  53.12  157.75  1981    12   66.33
1982-01  32539  53.12  157.75  1982     1   94.33
1982-02  32539  53.12  157.75  1982     2  131.33
1982-03  32539  53.12  157.75  1982     3  127.33
1982-04  32539  53.12  157.75  1982     4  101.33
1982-05  32539  53.12  157.75  1982     5   29.33
1982-06  32539  53.12  157.75  1982     6    0.00
...        ...    ...     ...   ...   ...     ...
1984-03  32539  53.12  157.75  1984     3  185.00
1984-04  32539  53.12  157.75  1984     4  154.33
1984-05  32539  53.12  157.75  1984     5   79.00
1984-06  32539  53.12  157.75  1984     6    0.00
1984-07  32539  53.12  157.75  1984     7    0.00
1984-08  32539  53.12  157.75  1984     8    0.00
1984-09  32539  53.12  157.75  1984     9    0.00
1984-10  32539  53.12  157.75  1984    10    0.00
1984-11  32539  53.12  157.75  1984    11   44.67
1984-12  32539  53.12  157.75  1984    12   76.33
1985-01    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1985-02    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1985-03    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1985-04    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1985-05    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1985-06    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1985-07    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1985-08    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1985-09    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1985-10    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1985-11    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1985-12    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN
1986-01  32539  53.12  157.75  1986     1  148.33
1986-02  32539  53.12  157.75  1986     2  160.00
1986-03  32539  53.12  157.75  1986     3  178.00
1986-04  32539  53.12  157.75  1986     4  131.00
1986-05  32539  53.12  157.75  1986     5   61.33
1986-06  32539  53.12  157.75  1986     6    0.00
1986-07  32539  53.12  157.75  1986     7    0.00
1986-08  32539  53.12  157.75  1986     8    0.00

print o_d.head(80)
```

Comment: This solution works except for the fact that all my sd values turn to 0s, not just the new lines that I have added.

Comment: Hmm, IIUC you need convert to `0` only rows from index `2009-02-28` to the end?

Comment: @jezreal There's also a year in between (1985) where this needs to be addressed as well. And I'd like these years to be "NaN" or -999 preferably as 0 can be an actual measurement.

Comment: Hmmm, I dont understand.After reindex you can get `NaN` before and after your data sample. Before you need `NaN` and after sample `0`? Or something else? Or between your data?

Comment: In the spots where I do have data, I have numbers where there are measurements and NaNs where the measurement is actually zero. That's why I use the line `o_d = o_d.reindex(idx,fill_value=0)` to turn my original NaNs into `0` values. Then, for the places where I want to insert the missing months from in my dataset (i.e. 1985 and 2010/2011), I want the `['sd']` column to be filled with `NaN`.

Comment: Can you add data sample and recommended output of data sample?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've added some sample data above.